# Filtering a CollectionView by multiple columns?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview that pulls in a bunch of information from a database. There are known values assigned to these that would be useful to sort by, but I only seem to be able to sort by one item at a time. Here is that working code:

```
private bool prodAreaFilter(object item)
{
    return (item as PCdata).ProductionArea.IndexOf(((ComboBoxItem)prodAreaComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}

private void prodArea_Combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView viewPA = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource);
    viewPA.Filter = prodAreaFilter;

    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource).Refresh();

    //MessageBox.Show(((ComboBoxItem)prodAreaComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());

}

private bool typeFilter(object item)
{
    return (item as PCdata).Type.IndexOf(((ComboBoxItem)typeComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}

private void type_Combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView viewType = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource);
    viewType.Filter = typeFilter;

    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource).Refresh();

    //MessageBox.Show(((ComboBoxItem)typeComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());

}
```

Instead of filtering together, they overwrite the other one. I think this is caused by them each having their own filtering logic, so I tried to combine it all into one filter:

```
private bool Filter(object item)
{
    return (item as PCdata).Type.IndexOf(((ComboBoxItem)typeComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    (item as PCdata).ProductionArea.IndexOf(((ComboBoxItem)prodAreaComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}


private void prodArea_Combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView viewPA = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource);
    viewPA.Filter = Filter;

    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource).Refresh();

    //MessageBox.Show(((ComboBoxItem)prodAreaComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());

}

//private bool typeFilter(object item)
//{
//    return (item as PCdata).Type.IndexOf(((ComboBoxItem)typeComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
//}

private void type_Combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView viewType = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource);
    viewType.Filter = Filter;

    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource).Refresh();

    //MessageBox.Show(((ComboBoxItem)typeComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());

}
```

This solution worked for me, but it was necessary to add logic to handle one combobox or the other being empty and switching the criteria accordingly.

```
            private void prodArea_Combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeComboBox.Text)) //If other combo is empty, only use one criteria for box that will have value
            {
                CollectionView viewPA = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource);
                viewPA.Filter = obj => ((PCdata)obj).ProductionArea.Contains(((ComboBoxItem)prodAreaComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());
            }

            else
            {

                CollectionView viewPA = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource);
                viewPA.Filter = obj => ((PCdata)obj).ProductionArea.Contains(((ComboBoxItem)prodAreaComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString()) &&
                                        ((PCdata)obj).Type.Contains(((ComboBoxItem)typeComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());
            }
            
                CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource).Refresh();
            
        }



            private void type_Combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prodAreaComboBox.Text))
            {
                CollectionView viewPA = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource);
                viewPA.Filter = obj => ((PCdata)obj).Type.Contains(((ComboBoxItem)typeComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                CollectionView viewPA = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource);
                viewPA.Filter = obj => ((PCdata)obj).ProductionArea.Contains(((ComboBoxItem)prodAreaComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString()) &&
                                        ((PCdata)obj).Type.Contains(((ComboBoxItem)typeComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());
            }

            
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstView.ItemsSource).Refresh();

        }
```

Comment: You're asking about sorting but showing us filtering code.

Comment: @Andy I thought they were the same thing, will correct the title. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example of filtering. Maybe this will help you.
If you have a button for filtering by "Name" and "Age"

```
private void btnFilterName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollectionView);
    view.Filter = obj => ((MyDataModel)obj).Name.Contains(txtFilterName.Text);
}

private void btnFilterAge_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollectionView);
    view.Filter = obj => ((MyDataModel)obj).Age == Convert.ToInt32(txtFilterAge.Text);
}
```

To filter by multiple columns, you can use the "&&" operator to combine multiple filter conditions in the same event.

```
private void btnFilterNameAge_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollectionView);
    view.Filter = obj => ((MyDataModel)obj).Name.Contains(txtFilterName.Text) && ((MyDataModel)obj).Age == Convert.ToInt32(txtFilterAge.Text);
}
```

To clear the filter, set the filter property to null in the button click event.

```
private void btnClearFilter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollectionView);
    view.Filter = null;
}
```

You can use if statements to apply the filter criteria

```
private void ApplyFilter()
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollectionView);
    view.Filter = obj => 
    {
        if (ComboBoxName.SelectedItem != null && ComboBoxAge.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            return ((MyDataModel)obj).Name.Contains(ComboBoxName.SelectedItem.ToString()) && ((MyDataModel)obj).Age == Convert.ToInt32(ComboBoxAge.SelectedItem);
        }
        else if (ComboBoxName.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            return ((MyDataModel)obj).Name.Contains(ComboBoxName.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
        else if (ComboBoxAge.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            return ((MyDataModel)obj).Age == Convert.ToInt32(ComboBoxAge.SelectedItem);
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

You can then call the ApplyFilter method in the SelectionChanged event of the comboboxes, so that the filter will be applied whenever a new item is selected. Call the ApplyFilter method if the selected item is not null, to prevent errors when the combobox is empty.

```
private void ComboBoxName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBoxName.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ApplyFilter();
    }
}

private void ComboBoxAge_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBoxAge.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ApplyFilter();
    }
}
```

If you want to clear the filter when both comboboxes are empty, you need to add a ClearFilter method and call it when both comboboxes are empty.

```
private void ClearFilter()
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollectionView);
    view.Filter = null;
}



if (ComboBoxName.SelectedItem == null && ComboBoxAge.SelectedItem == null)
{
    ClearFilter();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I think I have it implemented but because both of my comboboxes start empty, this crashes the app due to one side of the && not being set to an instance of an object. Is there a built in way to get around this, or will I have to make some if statements that use one criteria or both depending on the state of the comboboxes?

Comment: Doing this, are if statements required to prevent errors when one box is empty but the other one isn't? Please see updated post for example. Will still mark as solution because it works, but it needed extra code to prevent crashes.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that if one of the comboboxes starts empty, the filter will crash the app due to one side of the && operator not being set to an instance of an object. One way to get around this issue is to check if the comboboxes have a selected value before applying the filter. You can use an if statement to check if the combobox has a selected item and only apply the corresponding filter criteria if it does.

Comment: I will edit an example how you can use if statements to apply filter criteria based on the state of fields with a list

Answer (score 0):

A filter is a predicate which is applied for every item in your collection.

If it returns true, you get to see that item. If it returns false then you do not.

That filtering logic is run every time you add or remove an item or force refresh() on the collection. Unless you make it use live filtering, in which case when anything changes in the collection the whole thing is checked again.

All of which means that collectionview filtering is quite an expensive thing to use. You should carefully consider just how many items you have in your base collection. If there are a million rows and you have a user insert or delete rows out that then each time the whole collection is traversed and checked.

I wrote this article on filtering some years back:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx

Microsoft have ditched the technet gallery the source was on.

If you wanted flexible filtering based on more than one property then you could use the technique that demonstrates where the predicate itself checks a list of predicates. Want two columns to match, you add 2 predicates to the list. Want three, you add three. Below, criteria is a List.  Trueforall returns true if they're all true.

```
private bool dynamic_Filter(object item)
{
    Person p = item as Person;
    bool isIn = true;
    if (criteria.Count() == 0)
       return isIn;
    isIn = criteria.TrueForAll(x => x(p));

    return isIn;
}
```

In that sample you can pick from any or all of several criteria. The code that adds the predicates to that list looks like:

```
        criteria.Clear();

        if (yearsChosen > 0)
        {
            criteria.Add(new Predicate<Person>(x => yearsChosen < (
                (_zeroDay + (_now - x.BirthDate)).Year - 1)
                                                                ));
        }
        if (letterChosen != "Any")
        {
            criteria.Add(new Predicate<Person>(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(letterChosen)));
        }
        if (genderChosen != "Any")
        {
            criteria.Add(new Predicate<Person>(x => x.Gender.Equals(genderChosen.Substring(0, 1))));
        }

        PeopleView.Filter = dynamic_Filter;
        RaisePropertyChanged("PeopleView");
```